# Modify and Return variable of Parent Class - Python

Tags: python

I know this is probably a simple solution. But, it has stumped me. 
I simply need to access a method of the parent class, set a variable and then return it from the child class.

```
class Person(object):
    some code ...

    def setAge(self, age):
        #assumes age is an int greater than 0
        #sets self's age to age (in years)
        self.age = age
    def getAge(self):
        #assumes that self's age has been set
        #returns self's current age in years
        if self.age == None:
            raise ValueError
        return self.age


class Child(Person):
   code ...

    def setAge(self, age):
        Person(self.name).setAge(age)

    def getAge(self):
        return Person(self.name).age
```

I have even thrown some print statements in the parent class for the setAge method and gives the correct value. But, when I try to call it form the child. It gives me a None resulting in the raise ValueError

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instance variables are attached to the object; it doesn't matter if they are set via the parent class or the child class. You don't need to define `Child.setAge` or `Child.getAge` at all.

```
class Child(Parent):
    pass

c = Child()
c.setAge(5)
print c.getAge()
```

---

Also, don't test for equality with `None`; use

```
if self.age is None:
```

Comment: It doesn't fix the problem. I am not able to change the Parent class. I understand that since i would use pass for passing the methods to the child class i can solve in that matter. But the program that grades my code uses a def method in the child class to test if its correct or not. But, I do thank you for your response. And so very quickly.

Comment: You didn't read chepner's answer. You don't need to modify Parent. You only need to define the methods on Child that don't exist on Parent. This is the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, yes. You are both right. I retested. I left some bad code in there which through me off. Sorry any issues there. But thank you both. I know it was a sill issue. But, thanks for the tips :-D